# Deserialiazing list of elements with @Text annotation in Simple

Tags: java, xml, simple-framework

I have two classes, *Package* and *ModelRefObj*. Package contains two sets of *ModelRefObj*. 
I'm using Simple framework to parse their instances from XML, so I've created some JUnit tests. I'm able to parse *ModelRefObj* XML, but I'm getting the following exception when trying to parse a *Package*:

```
org.simpleframework.xml.core.ValueRequiredException: Empty value for @org.simpleframework.xml.Text(empty=, data=false, required=true) on field 'value' private java.lang.String cz.semanta.coc.domain.cognos.ModelRefObj.value in class cz.semanta.coc.domain.cognos.ModelRefObj at line 1
    at org.simpleframework.xml.core.Composite.readInstance(Composite.java:580)
    at org.simpleframework.xml.core.Composite.readText(Composite.java:467)
    at org.simpleframework.xml.core.Composite.access$200(Composite.java:59)
    at org.simpleframework.xml.core.Composite$Builder.read(Composite.java:1381)
    ...
```

Here is the XML I'm trying to parse:

```
<package> 
    <name>GO Sales (nalysis)</name>
    <visible>
        <refObj>[go_sales]</refObj>
        <refObj>[Filters and calculations].[Returns]</refObj>
    </visible>
    <hidden>
        <refObj>[gosales].[BRANCH].[BRANCH_CODE]</refObj>
        <refObj>[gosales].[BRANCH].[ADDRESS1]</refObj>
        <refObj>[gosales].[BRANCH].[CITY]</refObj>
    </hidden>
</package>
```

Here are my annotated classes:

```
@Root(name = "package")
public class Package {

    @Element
    private String name;

    @ElementList(name = "visible", entry = "refObj", type = ModelRefObj.class)
    private Set<ModelRefObj> visibleRefObjs;

    @ElementList(name = "hidden", entry = "refObj", type = ModelRefObj.class)
    private Set<ModelRefObj> hiddenRefObjs;

    Package() { }

    ...
}

@Root(name = "refObj")
public class ModelRefObj {

    @Text
    private String value;

    ModelRefObj() { }

    public ModelRefObj(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have implemented the classes you have and used the example xml you provided.

I created a main function to test

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
    Serializer serializer = new Persister(new Format("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding= \"UTF-8\" ?>"));
    File source = new File("sample.xml");
    Package p = serializer.read(Package.class, source);

    System.out.println(p.name);
}
```

The output is

```
GO Sales (nalysis)
```

Inspecting the object p in debug mode shows it has the two Sets with two and three elements.
Your code works fine for me.